# iOS UIManagedDocument locks app blocks main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading

I inherited a codebase recently from an offshore team and I have no experience with UIManagedDocument. In some situations when the app is first installed the initialization process completely locks up the app. It seems to be directly related to iCloud because when the network is off the app loads right away.

I tried doing various parts of this code in gcd blocks but there is some process that still escapes to the main thread and blocks all input.

Is there anyway to save or open asynchronously?

```
NSURL *_url = [[self applicationDocumentDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:MyDatabaseName];

self.document = [[MyCustomManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:_url];
self.document.delegate = self;

NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,nil];

NSURL *iCloudURL = [self iCloudDocumentsURL];
[options setObject:PrivateName forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
[options setObject:iCloudURL forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey];

self.document.persistentStoreOptions = options;

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[_url path]]) {
    [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
        if (success) {
            [self documentIsReady];
        }
    }];
}
else {
    // This can take 10 seconds sometimes.
    [self.document saveToURL:_url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
        if (success) {
            [self documentIsReady];
        }
    }]; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code dealing with the `self.document` before the `[self documentIsReady]` is called?

Comment: No. The app completely hangs on the save or open blocks on first launch. It varies between users and devices and my gut feeling is that it is tied into the iCloud history of the user with a previous version of the app.